# How do I report a bug against Ubuntu.com (the Ubuntu website)

Tags: community, canonical, ubuntu-website

Since the website and wiki have been redesigned, the text is not always readable. The footer text overwrites other text, the links are not uniform colors, and the colors use blend and blur the text.

What is the proper procedure to report these and other issues with this website? I have reported bugs in launchpad against https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website , but the team that maintains the ubuntu website is not part of that project. It is used instead for the wiki websites only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ubuntu-website` project on Launchpad *is* the right place. Their remit covers all the Ubuntu.* domain websites.

Whether or not you get any answers is another question. I suggest you post the bug there first and then follow the tip on the [contact us page](http://www.ubuntu.com/contact-us), and contact the webmasters:

> #### Web feedback
>
> If you have suggestions or corrections
> for ubuntu.com or canonical.com, email
> us at webmaster@ubuntu.com or
> webmaster@canonical.com.

**Edit:** I just had a little rummage around. I saw [one of your bugs there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/681978) and if I did triage there ***I would close that bug***. You're using a beta browser. The footer works just fine in Firefox 3.6 and the latest chromium. The bug is therefore most likely in Firefox and you should report it to Mozilla, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, when the bug is reported to launchpad, the website team will close it as "wrong place to report against ubuntu.com.

Comment: That's just not true. Just look at the hot bugs. I can see at least three triaged bugs there that are about the main website.

Comment: @charlie-tca edited: Just noticed that you're submitting bugs from Firefox 4 Beta. Sorry but nobody is going to take a rendering bug seriously from a beta browser. You need to take it up with Mozilla as it's most likely their issue.

Comment: @Oli: How would you recommend those of us testing Natty report bugs? The beta browser is installed in Natty be default. I did not choose to install it. Since I am running Natty as a tester,, I am not to report bugs?

Comment: @charlie-tca: In Firefox 4, click 'Help > Report a Problem'. This will collect some data and help you report the bug to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox.

Comment: @charlie-tca: Of course you can report bugs but when you're using beta software and you're using something outside of that (ie the website) you have to be conscious that the problem might not be with the website. At the very least you should announce what you're using when filing rendering issues so people can reproduce the error. I've edited the bug slightly to point this out.

Comment: In FF3 there's `Help -> Report Broken Website...` which might be a better way to get this upstream ASAP.

Comment: The emphasis on use of the beta firefox is really off track. I get the same results viewing the website usinjg firefox 3.6.

Comment: @charlie-tca Yeah I see it's just that your text-size is four levels higher than a standard system. That's just as relevant as using a non-standard browser but it does mean it's a valid bug. Make sure your reports reflect this.

Comment: But back to the topic, this is still the right place to file the bugs. I know it's been said that the design team are responsible for bugs like that but there's no reason they shouldn't interact with the `ubuntu-website` project (as it's one of their products too)

Comment: -1 You shouldn't close bugs just because they are reported against the wrong components, if the bug is related to firefox they just need to be updated.

Comment: @João How it that relevant to this question?

Comment: My comment was not for the question, it's for the last sentence from your answer. Charlie had a legitim concern an spend some effort to make sure the problem would be fixed, closing the bug would not help.

Comment: @Oli I just tried reporting a typo in the website, the `ubuntu-website` package is not available anymore, and will not allow you to file bug. I guess the only other option is by sending an email.

Answer (score 2):

As of 12 April 2016, the aforementioned canonical (lowercase c) website project on Launchpad was rendered obsolete, as one can see from its name ("Ubuntu Website - OBSOLETE") and its description:

> *OLD PROJECT - OBSOLETE AS OF 12 APRIL 2016*

The new description also points to the new location for development and bug reporting as it relates to the website:

> The ubuntu.com website project - PLEASE FILE BUGS HERE INSTEAD: https://github.com/ubuntudesign/www.ubuntu.com/issues/new

Additionally, there's a footer at the bottom of every page on ubuntu.com that directs to the right location:

> Legal information · Data privacy · Report a bug on this site

That last link leads directly to a [bug reporting template](https://github.com/canonical-websites/www.ubuntu.com/issues/new?body=%0a%0a%0a---%0a*Reported%20from:%20https://ubuntu.com/*) on the [GitHub project for the website](https://github.com/canonical-web-and-design/ubuntu.com), which is part of the [Canonical Web and Design Team](https://github.com/canonical-web-and-design).

Comment: +1; Thanks for this heads up :-) It is important to upgrade information that has become obsolete, but sometimes it is difficult to turn the focus from the old advice. Let us hope that people will continue reading past the accepted answer.