# How to report a bug in content (not interface) on Ubuntu.com?

Tags: downloads, launchpad, bug-reporting, ubuntu-website

I want to report a bug in the *content* on [the Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/). I don't know how to properly do this because:

- This is **not** a bug in the web server, or in the way a page is coded. It is a *content* problem, not an interface problem.
- This is **not** a broken link, or any other problem that could be trivially fixed by anyone who is not empowered to make *substantive content changes* to the website. It is unclear how this should *best* be fixed, and someone (or some group of people) will have to make a decision about that.
- This is **not** a bug in the help documentation hosted at https://help.ubuntu.com.
- This is **not** a bug in community-contributed content.

<sub>The bug I want to report is that, at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads, the "Text-based installation" section doesn't explain clearly to an inexperienced person that the text-based installation CD *is* the "alternate CD", and gives a link that doesn't make it easy for a novice to find the right `.iso` image. *I am only including this description here in case it helps people tell me how to report this issue. I am not trying to use AskUbuntu to file a bug report. Honest! ;-)*</sub>

Where should I go and/or who should I contact, to report this? Is there a Launchpad project for the website *content* that is neither community-contributed nor hosted in the `help` subdomain?

I know there is an `ubuntu-website` Launchpad project, and I have seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15077/how-do-i-report-a-bug-against-ubuntu-com-the-ubuntu-website) which says that *website problems* should be reported there. Is that also the right place to report "pure content" problems like the one I have encountered?

Since I originally posted this question, [aking1012](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2601/aking1012) has [pointed out in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4740551#4740551) that at least [one bug filed against `ubuntu-website` and accepted](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/883001) is, like this one, a non-trivial content issue. This suggests that I can just report this against `ubuntu-website`...but if anyone has a definitive answer with documentation (or just more examples of such bugs, or personal experience, or if you maintain the Ubuntu website), I'd still welcome an answer here.

Comment: wow, what happened to the old page, it now just throws you into a random mirror, what is any new user supposed to do with this? http://ftp.ticklers.org/releases.ubuntu.org/releases/

Comment: @mateo_salta Since you seem to be able to "reproduce" this and agree it's a bug, you may want to indicate you're affected at [the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/1005363) (with the green "This bug affects..." link). That should move the process along.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, there's currently a discussion going on [in the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/1005363) about how best to fix the website problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. Website (including content) issues should be reported against `ubuntu-website`.

Comment: Thanks, [I have reported the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/1005363).