# change link on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OSXApplicationsEquivalents

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

there is a link on this page that is broken:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OSXApplicationsEquivalents

the link for Gnome Do under the Quicksilver category links redirects to porn/flash games. I made an account and logged in to change it, but it says the page is immutable. I do not know how to contact someone to change the site. Please tell me what to do, or fix it yourself.

The correct link is: http://do.cooperteam.net/

Comment: File a bug against the site.

Comment: Close-voters: I agree with closing this. It *is* asking an (originally) on-topic question and was reasonable to ask here, but it's highly specific and about an issue [that is now fixed](http://askubuntu.com/a/506092/22949). So I'm VTCing as "describes a problem that can't be reproduced." @Mica Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Thank you for stepping up and working to fix this problem. Without you, it would not now be fixed. There's info about what to do in this situation, in [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/506092/22949). We'll likely close this question now but please don't be discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the page was immutable because it was being edited by someone else. But apparently not to fix this problem; the spam link you noticed was still there.

Alternatively, I think sometimes users log in, but are redirected to a page where they are still not logged in and cannot edit. Clicking to log in again usually fixes that (immediately, and without requiring reauthentication).

I've verified that this was really a spam link as you say, and that the correct link you've provided is indeed correct. After double checking that, I edited the page and corrected the problem as per your suggestion (crediting you in the comment history). **The link is fixed now.**

Ask Ubuntu is not the best place for reporting problems with Ubuntu documentation, but it *is* an appropriate place to ask questions, including about how to overcome problems using official Ubuntu resources like the documentaton wiki. So I think it was reasonable for you to ask about this here; nonetheless, we'll likely close this question.

Please feel free to continue posting "How do I fix..." questions. However, in this case, it appears your intention may have been *to report a problem.* Problems with documentation that you're unable to fix yourself can be reported as bugs, as [dobey says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506089/change-link-on-https-help-ubuntu-com-community-osxapplicationsequivalents#comment682200_506089).

**I believe [`ubuntu-website`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-website) is the correct package** for reporting bugs/problems in the Ubuntu help wiki, http://help.ubuntu.com/community/, since the other obvious possibility, [`ubuntu-community-website`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-community-website) is specifically for http://community.ubuntu.com.

Project descriptions:

- `ubuntu-website`: "The main ubuntu website, the wiki and associated sites."
- `ubuntu-community-website`: "Theme, bugs, and other resources for community.ubuntu.com"

Other relevant resources:

- [How to report a bug in content (not interface) on Ubuntu.com?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143006/how-to-report-a-bug-in-content-not-interface-on-ubuntu-com)

  (In which [Jorge Castro explains](https://askubuntu.com/a/143099/22949), "Website (including content) issues should be reported against `ubuntu-website`.")
- [ReportingBugs (on the wiki)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), though they're focused toward reporting bugs in Ubuntu software rather than other Ubuntu-related projects.